# Как скопировать каталоги в потоке с входными параметрами?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Учусь запускать методы в потоке. Подскажите как запустить метод в потоке, если в методе есть входные параметры?

Поток запускаю так:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DirectoryCopy));
thread.Start();
```

Пример метода DirectoryCopy:

```
    private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Как вариант, использовать делегат `ParameterizedThreadStart` вместо `ThreadStart`

Comment: пробовал, не подходит. Либо не хватает знаний правильно им воспользоваться

Comment: если я правильно понимаю при использовании делегата ParameterizedThreadStart вводные параметры типа object, а затем тип object приводить к необходимому типу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не надо думать о создании потоков вручную в таких случаях. 
Если действие поанируется как небольшое, то можно создать таск, который отправит работу в пул потоков

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Start");       

    await Task.Run((()=> DirectoryCopy("foo", "bar", true));        

    MessageBox.Show("Stop");        
}
```

Если действие долгое, то можно также создать таск, но при этом указать, что действие долгое, и пусть шедулер разбирается, как его лучше запустить (он скорее всего создаст поток сам)

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Start");   

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DirectoryCopy("foo", "bar", true),
                                            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    MessageBox.Show("Stop");
}
```

Comment: У меня 2 метода:копирование каталогов и установка. Эти 2 метода необходимо запустить в потоке, чтобы форма не висла. Причем последовательно: сначала скопировать каталоги и только по завершению копирования запустить в потоке метод установки. Через таск возможно не запускать следующий таск пока не выполнился предыдущий?

Comment: @patrik конечно, я потому и показал в примерах, где код начнет выполнение и где закончит. В примерах `"Stop"` выскочит только после того, как копирование отработает

Comment: Спасибо за решение, попробую

Comment: сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Вызвать метод в лямбда-выражении без параметров, например:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => DirectoryCopy("foo", "bar", true)));
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Не сработало, форма виснет

Comment: @patrik Жаль, конечно, не сработало. А поток сам по себе запустился? И что за форма такая? Что на ней еще есть?

Comment: @patrik Вот простое демо запуска потока: https://ideone.com/U8UCxv А с формой надо отдельно разбираться. Может сможете пример собрать? Попробуйте в отдельном проекте создать форму, в которой просто по кнопке запустите поток. Если будет виснуть, то получится пример.

Comment: через несколько минут форма развисла :|. На форме: combobox, button, progressbar и richtextbox.

Comment: @patrik А поток завершился? (~_~メ) Расскажите побольше о приложении. Что произойдет если в `DirectoryCopy` код заменить на `Thread.Sleep(10000);`? В методе где вызывается поток что-нибудь еще делается?

Comment: Ошибся: Форма развисла так как поток завершился. В методе где вызывается поток ничего кроме запуска этого потока нет. О приложении: копирование каталогов с подкаталогами с одного расположение в другое. Необходимо сделать так, чтоб форма не висла при выполнении метода

Comment: @patrik А покажите как Вы вызываете поток? Может какая-то лишняя переменная зацепилась.

Comment: По нажатию кнопки запускается метод. Вы правы закралось лишнее действие: thread.Join(); Я его использовал для того, чтобы до завершения потока дальше действия не выполнялись

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как дождаться правильно завершение потока для запуска следующего потока?

Comment: @patrik А нужно ли два потока? Может сделать один метод (скажем `CopyAndInstall`), который будет вызывать последовательно `DirectoryCopy` затем `install_uninstall`. Этот метод уже запускать в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Идея хорошая, попробую реализовать. Спасибо